# What's the correct usage of "over the phone" and "on the phone"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, differences, prepositions

What's the difference between *over the phone* and *on the phone* and what are their respective usages?

Comment: A person can tell you something over the phone or on the phone, but  a person using a phone is on the phone.